# Is there a word for the censored part of a video?

Tags: word-request

Sometimes, TV shows censor people's faces with pixels that hide the details, I am wondering if there's a noun for that, because I am trying to say something in an idiomatic way, but I find it hard without being able to refer to it.

For example, look at this sentence:

> They removed the **censored part**, thereby showing the face of the
>   person who decided to speak in anonymity.

Censored part sounds odd in this context, so is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When it's done as pixels, we use **pixelated** and **pixelation**.

You can write:

- They removed the **pixelation**, thereby showing the face of the person who decided to speak in anonymity.

Wikipedia gives "pixelization", but pixelate appears more common.

Many will write "pixelated" even when it would be more correct to use another word (eg [I News](https://inews.co.uk/opinion/comment/rachel-johnson-topless-sky-news-brexit-debate-trick/) referring to a blurred image as "pixelated"):

- **blurred out** (if the image is made blurry)
- **blacked out** (made black)
- **blanked out** (made black or white)
- **blocked out**
- **masked out** (any kind of blurring/rectangle/pixelation which prevents you seeing the face)

So you can have

- They removed the **blurring**, thereby showing the face ...

If it is actually censorship and not privacy, you can also write

- The removed the **censoring**/**censorship**, thereby showing the offensive symbol

Very occasionally you see **redaction bar** [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/apr/24/euro-candidates-turned-me-into-brexiteer) which would be appropriate for both privacy and censorship.  You could certainly write

- They removed the **redaction**, thereby showing the face ...

"Redaction" is quite a formal word.

Comment: Similarly you could say "They uncensored the video, showing their face/the symbol/etc..."

Comment: Pixelation *cannot* be "removed". You have to get your hands on an original copy.

Comment: @Mazura "Remove the pixelation" is something you'd hear in an edit or suite or broadcast unit, just as you might hear "Remove the subtitles".  Of course I agree with you that you can't take the pixelated or subtitled image and recreate the raw image, but certainly people use "Remove X" to mean "Don't add X".

Comment: @Mazura You would think that, but sometimes it's possible to uncensor badly done censorship.

Answer (score 3):

You ask if there's a noun for it. There is: pixelation.

So you could say

> They removed the pixelation from the face of ... .

You could also use *unpixelate* or *depixelate:*

> They unpixelated the face of the person ... .

or

> They depixelated the face of the person ... .

or

> They deobfuscated the face of the person ... .

Of course, you can say unpixelated the video, unpixelated that portion of the video that had obscured the face of ... . Etc.

You can search online and find many examples of *unpixelate* and *depixelate.*

Answer (score 2):

That type of censoring is called "pixelation" or "mosaic", so you can say "They removed the censoring mosaic...".  Or you could just say "they removed the censorship..."

The "censored part" would refer not to the mosaic, but to the face that was being hidden, or possibly the section of the video that contained censoring. This would not reveal the face that had been hidden.

Note that hiding faces in this way is usually about privacy, not censorship

Comment: If they "removed the censored part", then they just cut out every part of the video that had [word OP is asking for] in it.

Answer (score 1):

better alternative: ***uncensored***

Removing a censor is pretty much impossible; the data is lost. Likely what you have is *the original uncensored video*.

> They <strike>removed the censored part</strike> *released the uncensored video* which shows the face of a person who had requested anonymity, which was previously ***obfuscated*** through the use of [words in the other answers].

Comment: `obfuscated` isn't really normal usage here; no-on else has mentioned `masked` which would work better.

Comment: >To obfuscate something means to make it so that it isn't clear or transparent, much like dirty water makes it hard to see to the bottom of a pond. The verb shares its *ob-* root (meaning "over, completely") with ***obscure*, another word that can refer to the act of concealing something or making it more difficult to see or understand.** The rest of *obfuscate* comes from Latin *fuscus*, which means "dark brown" and is distantly related to our word dusk. – [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate)

Comment: @MikeBrockington - I suspect you feel that way because you're a programmer. In A/V it's probably called a mask. In layman's terms, *hidden* would be the best bet in place of *obfuscated*. As a learner, I might just wonder what sort of tech you have that can remove a 'mask' that they're wearing and digitally reconstruct someone's face.